# Maven : error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3 , I am using 1.6

Tags: maven

I have imported an existing Maven project into Eclipse IDE .
I have modified some  code in it , it compiled successfully , 
I am using Java 1.6 as compiler
and when i am trying to run maven clean  install  -X

Its giving the following error

could not parse error message:   (use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
D:\bayer\util\src\main\java\com\tata\bayer\util\BrokerageCalendar.java:179: error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3

```
   private static Hashtable<String, Boolean> nyseHolidays = new Hashtable<String, Boolean>();
                           ^

could not parse error message:   (use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
D:\bayer\util\src\main\java\com\tata\bayer\util\APIHttpXmlClient.java:27: error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
                        Class<? extends APIResponse> responseClass) {
                         ^
```

Please suggest any ideas as how to resolve this ??

Comment: Which version of Maven are you using and have you correctly configured JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 42):

Did you declare that you want to use java 1.6 in your project pom.xml?:

```
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.6</source>
                            <target>1.6</target>
                            <compilerArgument></compilerArgument>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
```

Comment: @AndreiBodnarescu for you. The finalName is irrelevant for this issue.

Comment: we did this way,
    <profile>            <id>1.6</id>
                         <build>
                               <plugins>
                                      <plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId><configuration>
<jdkLevel>1.6</jdkLevel>
<source>1.6</source>
<target>1.6</target>
<compilerArgument>1.6</compilerArgument></configuration</plugin></plugins></build>
We are using Java 1.7 and maven as 
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-07 00:46:01+0530)
    Java home: c:\Softwares\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre

Answer (score 26):

Configuring the Maven Compiler Plugin will fix the problem.  It turns out the problem was caused by the Maven3 package in the Ubuntu repository.  An alternate fix is to download Maven 3 from the Apache website which uses a more up to date Compiler plugin.

I wanted to know why this was happening when the documentation states the default Java source is 1.5.  To see what mvn is using for your compiler plugin use:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

My Maven Compiler Plugin was 2.0.2 even though I was using Maven 3.0.4 from the Ubuntu packages.
When I run the same command using Maven 3.0.4 from Apache I have a plugin version 2.3.2, which  defaults to Java 1.5 as expected.

Comment: This was the issue for me too, when using Maven package supplied from Ubuntu. Installing from Apache as suggested and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 5):

You have to configure the Maven Compiler Plugin.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.6</source>
    <target>1.6</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: it's worth noting that the default is 1.5 for compiler plugin >= 2.3. Maven 2.2.1 defaults to compiler plugin 2.0.2 but you can override it as described.

Comment: (by the way, there is a typo in the version of the example, but you can't make 1-character edits on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 3):

Another way that doesn't involve modifying the pom is to specify the source and target in the command line:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.compiler.source=1.6 -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.6
```

Note that this should be avoided generally as the build cannot be guaranteed to be repeatable this way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer this:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target>
    ...
```