# Why did maven suddenly start compiling with an older version of Java?

Tags: java, maven

I've been developing in Java using maven for a few days now. Today I edited my pom.xml based on [these instructions](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html). Suddenly running `mvn compile` is giving me errors as if I was compiling with an older version of java. Stuff like:

> error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3

Now I've paired my pom.xml back to its original content, and I'm *still* getting this error. I've done a `mvn clean` and deleted everything under target, and am still having this problem.

Here's a snippet of maven running the compilation phase:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building bahToBeh 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ bahToBeh ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/doug/lucid/bah-bio-demo/bahToBeh/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) @ bahToBeh ---
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to /home/doug/lucid/bah-bio-demo/bahToBeh/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.880s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 20 13:52:06 EST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/105M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project bahToBeh: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/doug/lucid/bah-bio-demo/bahToBeh/src/main/java/com/lucid/bahdemo/parsers/pm/MeshReader.java:[23,4] error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
```

And my paired-down pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.lucid</groupId>
  <artifactId>bahToBeh</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>bahToBeh</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.digitalpebble</groupId>
      <artifactId>behemoth-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>marc4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>marc4j</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This had been working fine up until today. I'm not sure what setting I might have changed or how I could have  munged up my project. I even double checked that the correct versions of java are installed:

```
doug@doug-VirtualBox:~/lucid/bah-bio-demo/bahToBeh$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_10"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_10-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)
doug@doug-VirtualBox:~/lucid/bah-bio-demo/bahToBeh$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_10
```

Here is JAVA_HOME

```
doug@doug-VirtualBox:~/lucid/bah-bio-demo/bahToBeh$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

Maven *IS* using the pom.xml I think it is, if I run `mvn -X compile` I get:

> DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.lucid:bahToBeh:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/doug/lucid/bah-bio-demo/bahToBeh/pom.xml

I've also deleted my maven repo `rm -rf ~/.m2` and saw maven redownload everything same problem.

**EDIT -- It suddenly works mysteriously**
I have no idea what happened, but suddenly now its working. I thought that one  thing I changed was I commented out a test. I went and uncommented out the test and then ran `mvn compile` and this time it compiled. Some state somewhere was out-of-sync and now things magically work?

I hate not knowing why my tools suddenly go wonky, so this is not an answer to the question, merely more information.

**EDIT -- and it also just suddenly STOPPED working again**
Looks like fully specifying the version to compile works though, so dingding thats the winner.

Comment: There is a Japanese haiku about it: "Yesterday it worked / Today it is not working / Maven is like that" :)

Comment: Did you change the JAVA_HOME by any chance?

Comment: It's not using a different version of java. You have the wrong target specified in your IDE.

Comment: @BrianRoach I'm building from the command line. Yes I use Eclipse, but how would that mess up maven?

Comment: Try renaming your repo to download all your dependencies again and them compile your project. May be the jar built earlier might be in your repo..!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven : error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3 , I am using 1.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597950/maven-error-generics-are-not-supported-in-source-1-3-i-am-using-1-6) solves your original problem. As of now, it would appear you're somehow not building using the POM you cut and paste above as it doesn't have the compiler plugin (unless it's included by default? can't remember).

Comment: @BrianRoach maven appears to be using the pom.xml I think it is. See my edit.

Comment: @BrianRoach Could there be a dependency that forces java compilation down to a lowest-common-denominator?

Comment: THen you're using an old version of maven and it's pulling 2.0.2 by default, which defaults to 1.3 as the target. See the answer linked to in my last comment.  The current compiler plugin defaults to 1.5

Comment: @Doug Are you started using generics in your code? Maybe you used 1.3, but there weren't generics in your code.

Comment: @tcb. Nope this worked this morning and suddenly started not working

Comment: Normally I down vote questions like this, but since I feel your pain at having to use maven +1

Comment: @DougT. - To summarize: The version of maven you are using is pulling v2.0.2 of the compiler plugin without you having specified a newer version in the pom. That version defaults to 1.3 as the target.

Comment: @BrianRoach well this is lovely. It started to work. I had some code commented out. Uncommenting it made it compile again!? Why?!? I hate crap that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Maven rarely makes sense. It does, however, make you cry on a regular basis. At least it does with me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the source and target java versions explicitly. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Comment: Yup! That did it. Thank you. Upping it.

Comment: Specifying it explicitly like above "solves" the problem, but does anyone know why/how maven is selecting 1.3 instead of highest available version? It seems like the very last fallback (a very poor one too...)

Comment: Defaulting to java1.3 compatibility has been the default maven behavior for many years now.  All I can say is *something* changed in the project or the user's configuration.  It could have been that the JDK was updated, maven was updated, a configuration file changed or was deleted that overrode the default (i.e. ~/.m2/settings.xml) or even a long overdue compile plugin version change could cause the default behavior to surface.

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround you can try this (given that it is very specific to an environment, this could help).

You can enforce the version of compilation using the plugin.
[Maven compilation plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

Good luck!

Comment: Please give a meaningfull summary of the link.

Comment: That's ... not a meaningful summary of the information. This isn't really an answer as-is, it's a link to information that might answer him.