# Jenkins and maven-compiler-plugin?

Tags: maven, tomcat, jenkins, maven-compiler-plugin

I'm having a problem configuring an Jenkins, I'm running jenkins from tomcat7 [ on ubuntu ] [ downloaded from apache, not installed via apt-get ]. I have installed java from Oracle. When I want to build an project, maven is saying that maven-compiler-plugin causing an problem:

```
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project npa: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
```

point is that I'm not using the maven-compiler-plugin in this version, I don't have this plugin even declared in any POM! I can't add anything to the pom by myself [ don't ask why ]

edit: 
full stack [ -X option in maven ]

```
14:02:37    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
14:02:37    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
14:02:37    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
14:02:37    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
14:02:37    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
14:02:37    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
14:02:37    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
14:02:37    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
14:02:37    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
14:02:37    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
14:02:37    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:02:37    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
14:02:37    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
14:02:37    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
14:02:37    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
14:02:37    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
14:02:37    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
14:02:37    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:98)
14:02:37    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:64)
14:02:37    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
14:02:37    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
14:02:37    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
14:02:37    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
14:02:37    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
14:02:37    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
14:02:37    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
14:02:37    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
14:02:37    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
14:02:37 Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
14:02:37    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:516)
14:02:37    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:114)
14:02:37    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
14:02:37    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
```

Comment: You cannot let the maven to compile the java source code without the maven-compiler-plugin. It is added by default.

Comment: how to change the default version of this plugin?

Comment: Please refer to the https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/

Comment: Yes, I've been there, the thing is I can't modify POM to change the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't compile. The compiler plugin is included by default by Maven. Look at the rest of the error message to work out why the code isn't compiling. Probably something to do with incompatible Java versions.

Edit: You are using an old version of the compiler plugin that defaults to Java 1.3 options, which is why it doesn't compile.

I suspect Jenkins may be pointing to Maven 2 (see this question [Maven : error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3 , I am using 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7597950/116509)). Make sure Jenkins is using the correct Maven 3 installation.

Comment: point is that I'm not using anything fancy or unusuall, mvn -version give me this:
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_43, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8

and as far as I know that is the Java version of the project

Comment: There will be build output explaining why the code doesn't compile. Please update the question with that.

Comment: it is the only error in the stack trace, other things are just standard debug messages

Comment: There isn't a line starting `[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : ` ??

Comment: With `-X`, what version of the compiler plugin does it show? Also, do you have the JDK installed, or just the JRE? Can you build the project on that server using the `mvn` command line tool?

Comment: 1) yest - with - X option
2) mvn clean install gives kind of strange output:[50,15] generics are not supported in -source 1.3
[ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
and other error similar to this [ annotation error] basically it thinks that I'm using java 1.3 which is weird because mvn -verions is saying that I have java 1.6. I've installed jdk from Oracle, jdk no jre onyl

Comment: Is is possible to point to maven 2? I haven't install maven in this version + mvn version is showing 3.0.4

Comment: Check the jenkins config, and look at the full build output to work out what version of maven is being run. Please also verify what version of the compiler plugin is being used (it appears to be 2.0.2 which is very old, and possibly the source of your problem)